# Image transfer between Angular and Web API Core

Tags: angular, image, asp.net-core-webapi, transfer

I have been trying to do image transfer between Angular and Web api core and vice versa from 3 days and I'm unable to do so. I have searched the internet a lot but i did not find any example for web api core.

I will be very thankful if some one can provide me link to documentation/examples or some tutorials.

Right now I'm doing data transfer between Angular and API through Json objects. How can i convert images to json for transfer?

Sorry if this is basic question as I'm new to it.

Comment: what error are you getting now?

Answer (score 0):

Why you convert the image to JSON?

You transmit your file directly to the service. This is the idea. The controller receives the file submitted POST

**BACKEND**

```
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;

                [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult UploadFile()
            {
                try
                {
                    var file = Request.Form.Files[0];

                    if (file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName;
                        string fullPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\wwwroot\upload", fileName);
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            file.CopyTo(stream);
                        }
                    }
                    return Json("OK");
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    return Json("Failed");
                }
            }
```

**FRONTEND**

```
export class UploadComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  upload(files) {
    if (files.length === 0)
      return;

    const formData = new FormData();

    for (let file of files)
      formData.append(file.name, file);

    const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', `api/uploadFile`, formData);

    this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response)
        //DONE
    });
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input #file type="file" (change)="upload(file.files)" />
```

Comment: @NoumanArshad finally, you resolve your problem?. Don't forget to mark the answer if my answer solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry, i was out of station.. in your example we are uploading image to API .. how to get image from api to front end?